# Entity Framework doesn't work with Nullable columns

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have problem with Entity Framework.

I have a table `Victor` with 3 nullable columns. When the wizard is finished, I can't see the nullable columns inside the `CreateVictor()` method, this method automatically is being generated by wizard not me.

After 4 hours I couldn't find any solution. This happens just for nullable column.

Answer (score 8):

This is a 'feature' rather than a bug. The idea is that only the non-null columns are required to create a 'Victor'. So they are the only columns included in the CreateVictor() method.

If you want to set the other properties, you can do this with the object returned by CreateVictor().

```
var victor = Victor.CreateVictor(...);
victor.Name = "name";
```

Comment: Thanks,This is a feature but it passed null value for null able columns Other developers have problem with this feature, but I expected   there was a property that we can set it up easily.